# why git modifies all files in the project, when it's done pull?

Tags: git, version-control

I have troubles when it's done **pull** to the repo, the git doesn't let me **merge** the conflicts don't make and auto merge and finally done pull anyway. That's makes **changes in all files** like if I were editing them.

That's have passed to me sometimes and it takes long time to fix it because, I have to check the files, saved the new code and finally revert them to do a new pull. If all it's fine done the pull and push, but again I have to write the new code that I saved.

I will explain the stepts that I follow when the trouble appears.

1.- I make a commit.

2.- I do a pull.

3.- Appear merge conflicts and modifies all files.

4.- I save the new code.

5.- I do a revert to the files (all).

6.- I do a pull again.

7.- And I do a push.

Then to write the new code.

1.- I take the code saved.

2.- I modify the files.

3.- It's done a commit.

3.- then a pull.

4.- Finally a push.

I use the phpstorm git plugin.

Comment: Will you please provide something concrete here? What does "modifies all files" mean?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Or one of the contributors is on Windows and the rest are on Mac or Unix? It could be a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) problem: one committer is using Windows newlines, another is using Unix newlines. To Git it would appear that every line of every file is being touched. Otherwise, please provide us with some more information like: the exact commands you are running, and the first page or so of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`.

Comment: It will be for the different OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn’t finish the pull merge when you solve the conflict files. The normal process to deal with merge conflict when pull from remote:

1. Decide the merge strategy, yours (keep your local changes), their (keep remote changes), or merge (keep changes what you want). For your situation, you click merge on phpstorm.
2. Modify the conflict files.
3. Commit for you modified files.

After these steps, the merge conflict from pull is finished.
So you can change your steps as:

1.- I make a commit.

2.- I do a pull.

3.- Appear merge conflicts and modifies all files.

4.- I save the new code.

5.- Commit the changes.

6.- Push to remote origin.

Comment: I will follow these steps.

Comment: Ok, just remember to do `git add .` and `git commit` after you solve all the conflict files.